# Unable to click on a button due to incorrect position in UI Automatorviewer

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, uiautomatorviewer

[UI Automator Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMLMU.png)

Whenever I use below command to click on `Ok` button, it clicks on the same position as pointing in `UI Automator viewer`. (screenshot)

I need to click on `Ok` Button.

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Ok']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when i am trying enter data on signup page Keyboards opens and due to that UI Automator screenshot giving wrong position of button. So what i have done is to use below command to hide the keyboard before clicking signup button.

```
Driver.navigate().back();
delay(3000);
Driver.findElement(By.id("btn_register_signup")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you have `resource-id`, the most reliable will be to use it for search:

```
driver.findElementById("confirm_button").click()
```

If it still click the wrong element you might need to wait a bit (for popup to be loaded) and then perform click

Comment: I have tried using findElemenyby,id but it clicks on the Tick Icon, Instead of OK button.

Comment: Is there any animation involved? Even if not, it's possible the screen isn't drawing completely before the click is sent. As mentioned in his answer, try to wait a bit before clicking.

Comment: The click is sent after appearing popup the problem is selenium click on the Tick icon instead of OK button, (You can see in the screenshot)

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot when i click in layout for Ok button it highlight on Tick Icon in UI Automator viewer

Comment: Run `driver.getPageSource()` right before click the OK button and print out what service return you, then attach it to your question. It speed up helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try :

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button and @text='Ok']")).click();
```

Comment: i have tried all the combination using xpath with class id text bounds etc, the problem is not it can't find the button, it is finding the button but at wrong place.. see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to click by coordinates?

***(Python code)***

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_id('confirm_button')
x = myElement.location['x']
y = myElement.location['y']
touchAction.tap(None, x, y, 1).perform()
```

I had the same problem when many layers are displayed at the same time... 
Hope it helps

**Update**

***(Java code)***

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElementById("confirm_button");
int x = myElement.getPosition().getX();
int y = myElement.getPosition().getY();
touchAction.tap(x, y).perform();
```

Comment: Can you please share the Java Code.

Comment: @user3410383 My answer was updated, check if it works